# Can I compare three averages if no independent variable?

Tags: anova, t-test, sas

I am not used to this type of data, and am not experienced with statistics so am really getting hung up.

This is an undergraduate research project.

I have done a total fecal collection on 12 horses. The idea is simple: to determine differences between days while horses are on a total collection. (Horses have to wear harness and be restrained in order to collect all the feces per day, so the stress, change in routine, etc could impact the measurements.) The horses were on collection for five days total. Each day I measured food intake (aka dry matter intake, abbreviated DMI), fecal output (DMO), and then I calculated dry matter digestibility (DMD) for each of the 5 days.

I used PROC MIXED of SAS to look for differences between days.

Class Horse Day;
Model DMI = Day/ddfm=kr;
Random Horse;
lsmeans Day/pdiff;
title 'Effect of day on DMI';
run;quit;

I did that same thing for my DMO and DMD...

The output gave me pdiff for all the combinations of days, for example that for DMO, my day 1 was different from days 3 and 4.

Was that the correct way to analyze the data?

Most research papers only report the collection averages, and some research papers use 3 days of collection, some use 4 days, and some use 5 days. Since I had differences in intake, and fecal output, which created differences in my calculated digestibility... I am interested in comparing the 3-day average to the 4-day average and 5-day average...

Is that possible? How would I do that?

Thank you very much for the help.

Kelly

Comment: It's not clear from your description what your hypothsis or research question is?  Can you clarify what you mean by "to determine differences between days while horses are on a total collection?"  Differences of what between days?  It doesn't make sense to me that you'd want to model DMI as the dependent variable in your model.

Comment: In general it's better not to compare overlapping samples (such as 3 day average vs 4 day average). If you compare "3 day average vs 4th day" and "4 day average vs 5th day", those are suitable contrasts which answer the same question (if the 4th day is significantly different from the three day average, the 4 day average is significantly different from the three day average)